# Sorting elements by decreasing frequency of occurence

Tags: c++, stl

I am trying to solve the question:

Print the elements of an array in the decreasing frequency if 2 numbers have same frequency then print the one which came first. (https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sort-elements-by-frequency/)

I am trying to implement the solution on my own. I have thought of creating the following data structure:

`map<int,pair<int,int>> mymap`

I am storing the number itself in the first `int`, and I am storing the index and count of the number in the array in the pair in the above map.

I want to write a custom comparator for sorting the pairs, something like this:

```
bool cmp(pair<int,int>&a, pair<int,int>&b)
{
    if (a.first == b.first) 
         return a < b;
    else
         return a > b;
}
```

I am still learning to write custom comparators. I am not able to wrap around my head, that how can I pass the comparator for sorting the map. Also, if pairs are sorted, then will the key in the map be sorted alongside?

Please let me know! Thanks!

Comment: While it's good as an exercise to do this sorting yourself, once you have done it and know all about it, throw it away and use [`std::stable_sort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/stable_sort) instead. :)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use maps for this, or better, not in this way. You can use a basic array `arr` that will contain elements and than use a `map cnt<int,int>` which will keep the number of occurrences of each element in the array and another one `firstIndex<int,int>` which will keep the index of the first appearance of the element. In this case the sorting function becomes simply:

```
bool cmp(int a, int b)
{
    if(cnt[a] != cnt[b]){
      return cnt[a] > cnt[b];
    } else {
      return firstIndex[a] < firstIndex[b];
    }
}
```

use it like this:

```
sort(arr, arr+n, cmp);
```

where `n` is the number of elements in the array.

Comment: I am assuming I will still pass the vector/array that is used for storing elements in the sorting function and comparator alongside? I mean, I will not be sorting the maps with comparator as input, right? Also, is there anyway I can optimize on some space here? I mean, any way you can suggest? I was thinking of using vector of pairs of pairs that will store all information at once and then pass it into the sorting function.

Comment: great. It works. Any input on the space optimization part? Thanks!

Comment: About space optimization what you can do, assuming that the maximum value of the array is not too big, is to drop the maps and use arrays both for counting occurrences and for remembering the first index appearance. Other than this I don't think there is some significant way to improve the code from memory consumption point of view.